# end Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm trying to build a custom kernel using *linux-4.14*. On my system I have *linux-4.10.0-38-generic* kernel and OS ubuntu 16.04LTS.

I have followed the following standard steps of compiling the kernel image as told by my instructor:

1. copied the config file from *linux-4.10.0-38-generic* to *linux-4.14*.
2. Installed *openss**, *libssl-dev* and *libncurse*
3. `make oldconfig`
4. `make menuconfig`
   --> General setup   ---> local version
   --> Loadable module ---> checked unloading and checksum
5. `make -j 4`
6. `make modules_install`
7. `make install`

When I tried to boot through this build os but I got the following error

> end Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes

Please help...
Thanks in advance....

[Error while booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeAR5.jpg)